Cant import PyQt5 even though its installed ubuntu 24.04
All of a sudden for some reason I tried to start up carla from the terminal and I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla", line 22, in <module>
    from carla_host import *
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla_host.py", line 40, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

So I tried doing the following from the terminal:
python3
>>> import PyQt5 

but I get no module found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

I have python3-pyqt5 installed via apt:
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.15.10+dfsg-1build6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.

Why all of a sudden is this broken. I haven't opened carla in a little while but it was working before and in this version of ubuntu. So whats changed and why I am getting this error all of a sudden? I have seen many different questions about PyQt5 module not found but they all basically say to just install it. But I already have it installed so not sure what to do here.

How did you install Carla?

sudo apt install carla but that is basically irrelevant. The quesiton is why can't I import PyQt5. As you can see by the question I can't import it at all I only noticed it because I tried to open carla from the terminal.

I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?
